# How can I check if my Bluetooth devices are vulnerable to a KNOB attack?

Tags: exploit, bluetooth

On Linux and/or macOS, how can I check if a device is vulnerable to a [Key Negotiation of Bluetooth (KNOB) Attack](https://knobattack.com/)?

And if a device is vulnerable, is there something I can do to mitigate the danger?

Comment: I'd suggest you visit the following link that has a POC by the same people who found the vulnerability: https://github.com/francozappa/knob/blob/master/poc-internalblue/README.md